# VirtualBox - Windows 10 Host + Linux Mint 19 Guest - All ports (8989, 9091, etc) work on guest, but NOT on Lan

Tags: linux, virtualbox, transmission

EDIT: Solution Found.
In my case, I needed to go into the network settings, in the identity tab change the Firewall Zone to "trusted".

My setup:

Host: Windows 10

Virtualbox: Version 6.1.36

Guest: Linux Mint 19 Tara

Network: Bridged mode, IP 192.168.0.x

Various services (Transmission, etc) are accessible within the guest.  I.E., I can navigate to their web pages locally.  Transmission, for example, can be accessed within the guest via 192.168.0.x:9091.  However, it and all other services are NOT accessible outside the guest, on the Lan.

- Guest Firewall (ufw) is disabled for testing purposes, issue remains.
- Guest VPN (private internet access) is disabled for testing purposes, issue remains.
- I can ping the guest, and the guest can ping out to devices on the Lan.
- Guest can browse the internet.
- Guest SSH is operational.
- (edited to add) - bypassed windows firewall by trying to access on android phone, same issues

It's a real head-scratcher.  Everything was working fine and then it just stopped working.  As it happens, I have a backup of this VM, and when I spin up the backup instance, THAT works perfectly.  For about three days, and then everything stops working again.  So this issue is absolutely reproducible, but I have zero knowledge of how to track something like this down.  It seems all the TCP/IP stuff is in order, and it seems the apps should all work fine.  But something is preventing them from being accessible outside the guest/on the Lan.

Any help would be highly appreciative.  Please tell me what log files you might need/how to retrieve them.  Thank you.